# collecting HashMap<String, List<String>> java 8

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-8, collectors

I want to be able to convert a `List` to a `HashMap` where the key is the `elementName` and the values is a list of something random (in this case its the Element Name). So in short I want (`A->List(A), B->List(B), C-> List(C)`). I tried using `toMap()` and passing it the `keyMapper` and `ValueMapper` but I get a compilation error. I would really appreciate if someone can help me out.

Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D");
    Map<String, List<String>> map = list.stream().map((element)->{
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(element, Arrays.asList(element));
        return map;
    }).collect(??);
}


Function<Map<String, String>, String> key = (map) -> {
    return map.keySet().stream().findFirst().get();
};

Function<Map<String, String>, String> value = (map) -> {
    return map.values().stream().findFirst().get();
};
```

=== **This worked for me**

Thanks for all the help guys! @izstas "they should operate on the elements" helped a lot :). Actually this is what I was looking for to be exact

```
public static void test2 (){
    Function<Entry<String, List<String>>, String> key = (entry) -> {
        return entry.getKey();
    };
    Function<Entry<String, List<String>>, List<String>> value = (entry) -> {
        return new ArrayList<String>(entry.getValue());
    };
    BinaryOperator<List<String>> merge = (old, latest)->{
        old.addAll(latest);
        return old;
    };

    Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("A", Arrays.asList("A1", "A2"));
    map1.put("B", Arrays.asList("B1"));
    map1.put("D", Arrays.asList("D1"));

    Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("C", Arrays.asList("C1","C2"));
    map2.put("D", Arrays.asList("D2"));

    Stream<Map<String, List<String>>> stream =Stream.of(map1, map2);
    System.out.println(stream.flatMap((map)->{
        return map.entrySet().stream(); 
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(key, value, merge)));
}
```

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: Post your source code, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am not sure but as far as I know in your map part whatever you have from left side has to match with the right side, so you should return element not map I think :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Functions `key` and `value` you have defined in your code are not correct because they should operate on the **elements** of your list, and your elements are not `Map`s.

The following code works for me:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
Map<String, List<String>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Arrays::asList));
```

First argument to `Collectors.toMap` defines how to make a key from the list element (leaving it as is), second argument defines how to make a value (making an `ArrayList` with a single element).

Comment: Did you consider replacing (element) -> element with Function.<String>identity()?

Comment: @Jeff Oh, that's a nice suggestion. I will update my answer. By the way, it appears to work for me without having to specify the type parameter explicitly.

Comment: Cool. Yeah the type is not needed. It was a copy/paste.

Comment: I've updated the question with the solution I was looking for. Thanks !

Comment: This code do not works for multiple elements, try with `List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "A");`

Answer (score 102):

You can use the `groupingBy` method to manage aggregation, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "A");
    Map<String, List<String>> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()));
}
```

If you want more flexibility (for example to map the value and return a Set instead of a List) you can always use the `groupingBy` method with more parameters as specified in javadoc:

```
Map<City, Set<String>> namesByCity = people.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCity, mapping(Person::getLastName, toSet())));
```

Comment: groupingBy does exist??

Comment: I fixed the example sorry. The method `groupingBy` is a static method in `java.util.stream.Collectors`.

Comment: Brilliant on the Map<City, Set<String>>. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for all the help guys! @izstas "they should operate on the elements" helped a lot :). Actually this is what I was looking for to be exact

```
public static void test2 (){
    Function<Entry<String, List<String>>, String> key = (entry) -> {
        return entry.getKey();
    };
    Function<Entry<String, List<String>>, List<String>> value = (entry) -> {
        return new ArrayList<String>(entry.getValue());
    };
    BinaryOperator<List<String>> merge = (old, latest)->{
        old.addAll(latest);
        return old;
    };

    Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    map1.put("A", Arrays.asList("A1", "A2"));
    map1.put("B", Arrays.asList("B1"));
    map1.put("D", Arrays.asList("D1"));

    Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put("C", Arrays.asList("C1","C2"));
    map2.put("D", Arrays.asList("D2"));

    Stream<Map<String, List<String>>> stream =Stream.of(map1, map2);
    System.out.println(stream.flatMap((map)->{
        return map.entrySet().stream(); 
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(key, value, merge)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where I have a list of Map.Entry<X, Y> and was trying to aggregate them into a Map<X, List>.
Here just the `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey))` does not work simply.

The way to go was:

```
list.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList()))))
```

Kudos to Piet from here: https://coderanch.com/t/755986/java/Create-Map-existing-List-Entry